# An example of where normal order has less steps than applicative order?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I can't seem to come up with an example of this and wondering if there is such a case?  I know if I have an expression where applicative order doesn't terminate that normal order may still terminate.  I'm wondering though if there is an example where both orders terminate but normal order has fewer steps.

Comment: What about the constant function `const 42 (fact 5)`. In normal order you'll get the result `42` without having to calculate `fact 5`. In applicative order you'd have to calculate `fact 5 = 120` even though the result is never used.

Comment: @AaditMShah: What is `const`?  What is 42?  I've never heard of these things.  All I know about are functions and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(λ p. λ q. q) ((λ x. λ y. λ z. ((x y) z)) (λ w. λ v. w))

With some whitespace:

```
(λ p. 
   λ q.
     q
)
(
  (λ x.
     λ y.
       λ z.
         ((x y) z)
   )
   (λ w.
      λ v.
        w
   )
)
```

In normal order, the outermost reduction can be performed first, reducing directly to the identity combinator in one step.  Applicative order will get there too, but it takes much longer since the x-y-z-w-v expression needs to be evaluated first.

Note that the x-y-z-w-v expression isn't even *used*.  You can think of normal order as a sort of lazy evaluation: expressions are only evaluated or reduced when they are used.  So you just build a formula that doesn't use one of its arguments and you immediately have an example of this kind of efficiency win.

Comment: Thanks!  Would this be correct then?  (λy. 5)(λx. (x+1))2 - I get 5 with normal order in one step because there are no free occurrences of y but it would require two steps with applicative order because I have to first evaluate 2 + 1 before reaching 5?

Comment: @pad11: Yes, but your parentheses are messed up.  Also, when working with typed lambda calculus, it is preferable to say so explicitly.  In untyped lambda calculus, there's no such thing as 2, much less addition, unless you define those things yourself using e.g. church numerals.

Comment: Ah thanks for correcting that and for the added info!  I wasn't aware of the distinction between typed / untyped

Answer (score 0):

In a lambda expression, any variable bound within an abstraction can be used zero or more times in the body of the abstraction.

- **Normal order** evaluates the argument n times, where n is the number of times it is used in the body.
- **Applicative order** evaluates the argument exactly once, irrespective of the number of times it is used in the body.

Comparison

1. If argument is used **exactly once**, both normal order and applicative order will have same performance.
2. If the argument is used **more than once**, applicative order will be faster.
3. If the argument is used **zero times**, normal order would be faster.